# Linux equivalent to BSD's vis(1) utility

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, terminal, freebsd

I have a bunch of `zsh` scripts for cli-based tasks, and developed most of them on FreeBSD and MacOS (both BSD Unix flavors)

I've been using Ubuntu lately, and noticed some of my scripts were broken. One of the few scripts I have yet to fix depends on [`vis(1)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vis&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=freebsd), a common utility to translate unprintable characters to their "visible" equivalent. For instance, [`BELL` characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) become nice `^G`s  and unsightly ["*escapes*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character) become `\e`'s after `echo`ing and piping them through `vis`.

It's very handy when debugging screen output that would otherwise mess up or even lock up the screen.

Usually, when not installed with the base system as is the case on FreeBSD, `vis(1)` comes bundled in the terminfo packages, as is the case on MacOS, where it's available even on Homebrew.

However I can't find it on Linux, or in the terminfo packages for my distribution. In fact,  `vis(1)` appears to be [some sort of `vi` clone](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vis/+publishinghistory) on Ubuntu!

The closest thing I could find was on the [libbsd-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libbsd-dev/filelist) package, but this package only includes the library, man page and C-header definitions `vis.h` for the system calls `strvis(3)` and `strunvis(3)`.

Is there a utility with similar functionality available on Linux? Which package should I install to get it; preferably for Ubuntu?

Comment: Bug report for the `vis` editor from 2016: https://github.com/martanne/vis/issues/338

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, there is a 100% portable solution, with the aditional perk of not depending on any external utility at the whim of packagers and maintainers!

After scratching the surface of the gargantuan `zsh` man pages, I found an obscure and probably little known feature.

So we have *brace expansion* for variables (or parameters in `zsh`-speak) it just so happens that there are a whole bunch of flags you can use when doing brace expansion of a variable, and remarkably handy things can be done with such flags. So if i store unsightly apnd potentially terminal-locking termcaps in a variable, all i have to do is use the `(V)` flag when `echo`ing `print`ing or at some point while assgning to a new variable. and it wll have the exact same effect as the aforementioned `vis(1)` utility. Internally it's actually `strvis(3)` reimplemented.
so my solution was this:

```
zmodload zsh/terminfo

typeset terminal_reset_sequence=$terminfo['rs2'] #toxic! locks terminal if echoed!
echo ${(V)terminal_reset_sequence} # Perfectly safe like piping trough vis(1)
```

---

as a bonus, i found the `(Q)` and `(z)` flags, that will do correct shell quoting (`(Q)`) on any string containing slashes, octals, single and double quotes. Magically makes them shell-safe, while `(z)` if i understand it correctly, will "*peel away*" one level of quoting in a shell-safe manner on any nested-quoted string. Wish I knew about these two years ago! :C

Comment: Huh, in which Linux distro is _zsh itself_ not an "external utility"?

Comment: I use it as my default shell on every system. Once it's set, it is no external utility, it is THE system shell. so, for example i'm sure all my scripts will be portable across OSs, since i'm using a built in feature of the shell, not a system dependent external utility, as was the case with `vis(1)` If i need to move my scripts to BeOS twomorrow, and there's a `zsh` port for BeOS, (as there is in fact one for android) there will be no need to tweak any of them. as a matter of fact, i just read that zsh implements some pretty large stuff like `zftp` and `ztcp` for this purpose exactly.

Answer (score 3):

GNU coreutils' `cat` has that function (infamously) built in – if you don't mind it breaking UTF-8:

```
cat -v
```

There is a similar function in `sed`, though it also folds lines to 80 bytes:

```
sed -n l
```

Something more portable would be:

```
perl -p -e 's/[^\t\n\x20-\xFF]/sprintf("\\x%02X", ord($&))/ge'
```

I think this would handle Unicode better:

```
perl -C -p -e 's/[^\n\P{Other}]/sprintf("\\x{%04X}", ord($&))/ge'
```

Comment: hmmm.. didn't know cat OR sed could do that.... :/ we BSD refugees are always caught in GNU's hide-a-feature game  (like whack-a-mole, but instead of a hammer, you have to read *info* pages (what was wrong with `man`?)) Anyway its a good catch! However, diving deep trough manuals i found a portable solution as it will not depend on system-specific utilities, but relies on a standard feature of the zsh shell itself! so no more portability issues as long as zsh is available on the target system!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `vis` on BSD, but I found `showkey -a` is very useful for determining ASCII escape codes in Linux terminal. It could even catch and display ASCII escape codes for `Backspace`, `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+D`, `Enter` and arrow keys.